# SpriteKit - Action with completion block, or not?

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

What is the better approach:

For example if I want to add a node to the scene and play some animation, or run some other code which I want to execute right after the node is added to the scene, but not before, what is a preferred thing to do:

This:

```
[scene addItem:item];
[item playAnimation];
[item runSomeTimeRelatedCode];
```

or to run this same code within action with completion block:

```
 SKAction *action = [SKAction runBlock:^{
       [scene addItem:item];

    }];
    [scene runAction:action completion:^{
       [item playAnimation];
       [item runSomeTimeRelatedCode];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code fragment just needlessly delays execution and makes the code more complex to write. In short, it makes no sense to use it.